# Markitup editor and image upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, markitup

Does any of you experts know of any plugins for [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) which does an implementation of an image upload for mvc.net (or asp.net forms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as information, I found the [following](http://pastebin.ca/1763467) code snippet I am going to try to redo to fit my application.